# AnyLogic: Creating a rectangular wall with a code

Tags: java, api, anylogic

I hope you having a great day.

I am recently developing a simulation model with AnyLogic and I want to make a wall area from my database. To do that, I made a set of code lines as shown below.

```
RectangularWall Thiswall = new RectangularWall();
Thiswall.setPos(0, 0, 0);
Thiswall.setSize(1000, 1000);
Thiswall.setVisible(true);
Thiswall.setOwner(this);
Thiswall.initialize();
```

I put the code in my Main Agent but it is not visible when I run the code.

[Screenshot of Main Agent Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvcaO.jpg)

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add shapes programmatically, you need to add them to the presentation, so add the following code anywhere after defining your RectangularWall:

```
presentation.add(Thiswall);
```